# C++ issues with concatenating variables and strings into a file

Tags: c++, string, variables

I am trying to create a program that creates quizzes and stores the data into a file. This is my first attempt my code is sloppy and possibly more issues than what I want to fix. The primary issue I can not seem to find a solution for is when I use `file << user_question;` it just stores the question the user wants but I want to also write next to the question the current number the question is. An example of my desired output is this "**1.) How are mushrooms grown?**"  As the user generates more questions the number will change as the **current_numbered_question** variable goes up.

`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int number_of_questions;
int current_numbered_question = 0;
int user_choice;
string user_question;
string user_answer;
void quizBuilder();


//Step 1. Welcome user and explain how to use the quiz maker
//Step 2. How many questions would you like to ask?
    /* 
    * all the question options and records answers and kills program
    * once they have met the number of questions
    */ 
//step 3. Begin with asking what type of question it will be.
    //- multiple choice
    //- short written answer
    //- connect defintion to word
    //- True or False
//step 3.


void multipleChoice() {

    fstream file;

    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "Error when opening file.";
    }

        file.open("quiz.txt", ios::out);

        cout << "What is your question?\n";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, user_question);


        if (file.is_open())
        {
            file << user_question;

            cout << "What is the first multiple choice answer you would like?\n";
            getline(cin, user_answer);

            file << user_answer;
    
        }

        return;
}


void quizBuilder() {
    
    do {

        cout << "What type of question would you like to create?\n";
        cout << "1. multiple choice\n";
        cout << "2. short written answer\n";

        cout << "Type of question: ";
        cin >> user_choice;
        cout << "\n\n";

        current_numbered_question++;

        if (user_choice == 1) {
            multipleChoice();
        }
        else {
            cout << "Issues";
        }
    } while (current_numbered_question != number_of_questions);
}


string greeting() {

    cout << "Welcome to the Quiz Maker!\n";
    cout << "How many questions would you like to make for this quiz?\n";
    cout << "Number of questions: ";
    cin >> number_of_questions;
    cout << "\n\n";

    quizBuilder();
    
    return 0;
}



int main()
{
    fstream file; //This library creates and manages files using c++
    file.open("quiz.txt", ios::out); //ios::out is write mode

    cout << "File was successfully created.\n\n";

    file.close();

    greeting();

    return 0;
}
```

`

I tried several different youtube videos on strings, concatentaion, file write and read using variables but none seemed to produce what I want or just errors.

Simply put when user provides the question they want written into the file it gets numbered and then stored.

Example of output:

12.) What is the Earth's circumference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `<<` operator multiple times like this:

```cpp
file << current_numbered_question << ".) " << user_question;
```

Comment: I have no idea what I was doing wrong. I had tried this prior to the post. Thank you for answering. I just tried this once again and sure enough this works.